# Any advantages of having Raid0 with single drive?

Tags: raid, raid-0, hardware-raid

Are there any advantages of having a Raid0 configuration with a single drive? Both Intel controllers and LSI controllers I'm using allow for Raid0 creation using a single drive.

Is there any performance gain / whatnot by doing this? I've found [this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/471597/what-is-a-single-drive-raid-0-array) which does mention taking advantage of cache when using external controller.

Is there anything I'm missing here? Just as a point of reference, most Dell business systems I've been working with ship with single drive in Raid0, hence the question.

Answer (score 5):

Putting a single disk into RAID 0 makes it still behave like a single disk but keeps the OS from seeing it.  You rarely would want to do this.  The only time that I can imagine wanting this is if you wanted your RAID card and out of band management system to handle all monitoring and alerts and you wanted to hide this all from your operating system.  If you use RAID 0 the OS cannot see the drive any more and can only see the RAID array.  Likely you would only do this for a lab where you want to mimic a full RAID array for testing purposes.  You would never deploy to production in this way.

Answer (score 2):

Oddly, I was just forced to do exactly this as the only means to get Windows 10 to see the hard drives on out-dated server hardware.  For whatever reason the passthrough mode would not function so I had to put the system drive and the data archive drive each in their own drive-group as RAID0 so they would pass the virtual-drives to the bios... took me over 4 hours of getting no-where before I figured that one out...